# url string getting clipped

Tags: c#

Why is the full url not being retained?

I am using

```
Context.Request.Form["Url"]
```

[image]

Comment: To me it looks like the first portion is `UrlEncoded` but the rest isn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&clienttype=rss` is another param of the request and not part of the url. If it were part of the url, the `&` would be URL encoded.